# Change input and slide in ui slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, slider

I have got two sliders and inputs. When we changing number in the top now, number and slide in the bottom block don't change. What should I complete?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $doorwayWidth = $(".js-doorway-width"); //  ширина
  var $doorWidthDisable = $(".js-door-width"); //  ширина disable
  var $doorwayHeight = $(".js-doorway-height"); //  высота
  var $doorHeightDisable = $(".js-door-height"); // высота disable
    
  var doorwayWidthSlider = $( "#doorwayWidthSlider" ).slider({
      range: "min",
      min: 650,
      step: 50,
      max: 1000,
      value: 1000,
      slide: function( event, ui ) { 
          var totalWidth = ui.value ;
          $doorwayWidth.val(  ui.value );
          var doorSize = calcDoorSize(totalWidth);
          doorWidthSlider.slider("option","value", doorSize[0]);        
      },
      change: function(event, ui){
          $doorwayWidth.val(  ui.value );        
      } 
  });
  $doorwayWidth.val( doorwayWidthSlider.slider( "value" ) );
  $doorwayWidth.val(700).focusout(function() {
         $( "#doorwayWidthSlider" ).slider("value", this.value);
     }).focusout();


  var doorWidthSlider = $( "#doorWidthSlider" ).slider({
      range: "min",
      disabled: true,
      min: 600,
      step: 100,
      max: 900,
      value: 900,
      change: function(event, ui){
          $doorWidthDisable.val(  ui.value );       
      } 
  });
  $doorWidthDisable.val( doorWidthSlider.slider( "value" ) );


  var sliderOptions = [
      {
          minWidth: 650,
          maxWidth: 700,
          minHeight: 2040,
          maxHeight: 2080,
          doorWidth: 600,
          doorHeight: 2000
      },
      {
          minWidth: 750,
          maxWidth: 800,
          minHeight: 2040,
          maxHeight: 2080,
          doorWidth: 700,
          doorHeight: 2000
      },
      {
          minWidth: 850,
          maxWidth: 900,
          minHeight: 2040,
          maxHeight: 2080,
          doorWidth: 800,
          doorHeight: 2000
      },
      {
          minWidth: 950,
          maxWidth: 1000,
          minHeight: 2040,
          maxHeight: 2080,
          doorWidth: 900,
          doorHeight: 2000
      }
  ];

  function calcDoorSize(totalWidth) {
      var doorWidth = null;
      for (var i = 0; i < sliderOptions.length; i++) {
          if (totalWidth >= sliderOptions[i].minWidth && totalWidth <= sliderOptions[i].maxWidth) {
              doorWidth = sliderOptions[i].doorWidth;
              break;
          }
      }
      return [ doorWidth];
  }
  
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 <link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/hot-sneaks/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />


 <div>
     <div>
         <label>Width</label>
         <input class="js-doorway-width" name="calculatorPvhSquare" type="text">
     </div>

     <div>                         
         <div id="doorwayHeightSlider"></div>
         
         <img src="" alt="">
         
         <div id="doorwayWidthSlider"></div>
     </div>
 </div>             

    <div>
        <div>
            <label>Width</label>
            <input class="js-door-width" type="text" disabled>
        </div>
        <div>                         
            <div id="doorHeightSlider"></div>            
            <img src="" alt="">            
            <div id="doorWidthSlider" ></div>            
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update `focusout` event of `$doorwayWidth` to the following to recalculate `doorSize` and set slider value for `doorWidthSlider`.

```
$doorwayWidth.val(700).focusout(function () {
    $("#doorwayWidthSlider").slider("value", this.value);
    var totalWidth = this.value;
    var doorSize = calcDoorSize(totalWidth);
    doorWidthSlider.slider("option", "value", doorSize[0]);
}).focusout();
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 var $doorwayWidth = $(".js-doorway-width"); //  ширина
 var $doorWidthDisable = $(".js-door-width"); //  ширина disable
 var $doorwayHeight = $(".js-doorway-height"); //  высота
 var $doorHeightDisable = $(".js-door-height"); // высота disable

 var sliderOptions = [
  {
   minWidth: 650,
   maxWidth: 700,
   minHeight: 2040,
   maxHeight: 2080,
   doorWidth: 600,
   doorHeight: 2000
  },
  {
   minWidth: 750,
   maxWidth: 800,
   minHeight: 2040,
   maxHeight: 2080,
   doorWidth: 700,
   doorHeight: 2000
  },
  {
   minWidth: 850,
   maxWidth: 900,
   minHeight: 2040,
   maxHeight: 2080,
   doorWidth: 800,
   doorHeight: 2000
  },
  {
   minWidth: 950,
   maxWidth: 1000,
   minHeight: 2040,
   maxHeight: 2080,
   doorWidth: 900,
   doorHeight: 2000
  }
 ];

 var doorwayWidthSlider = $("#doorwayWidthSlider").slider({
  range: "min",
  min: 650,
  step: 50,
  max: 1000,
  value: 1000,
  slide: function (event, ui) {
   var totalWidth = ui.value;
   $doorwayWidth.val(ui.value);
   var doorSize = calcDoorSize(totalWidth);
   doorWidthSlider.slider("option", "value", doorSize[0]);
  },
  change: function (event, ui) {
   $doorwayWidth.val(ui.value);
  }
 });
 $doorwayWidth.val(doorwayWidthSlider.slider("value"));

 var doorWidthSlider = $("#doorWidthSlider").slider({
  range: "min",
  disabled: true,
  min: 600,
  step: 100,
  max: 900,
  value: 900,
  change: function (event, ui) {
   $doorWidthDisable.val(ui.value);
  }
 });
 $doorWidthDisable.val(doorWidthSlider.slider("value"));

 $doorwayWidth.val(700).focusout(function () {
  $("#doorwayWidthSlider").slider("value", this.value);
  var totalWidth = this.value;
  var doorSize = calcDoorSize(totalWidth);
  doorWidthSlider.slider("option", "value", doorSize[0]);
 }).focusout();

 function calcDoorSize(totalWidth) {
  var doorWidth = null;
  for (var i = 0; i < sliderOptions.length; i++) {
   if (totalWidth >= sliderOptions[i].minWidth && totalWidth <= sliderOptions[i].maxWidth) {
    doorWidth = sliderOptions[i].doorWidth;
    break;
   }
  }
  return [doorWidth];
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/hot-sneaks/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div>
 <div>
  <label>Width</label>
  <input class="js-doorway-width" name="calculatorPvhSquare" type="text">
 </div>

 <div>
  <div id="doorwayHeightSlider"></div>

  <img src="" alt="">

  <div id="doorwayWidthSlider"></div>
 </div>
</div>

<div>
 <div>
  <label>Width</label>
  <input class="js-door-width" type="text" disabled>
 </div>
 <div>
  <div id="doorHeightSlider"></div>
  <img src="" alt="">
  <div id="doorWidthSlider"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: O, thank you! I've got an idea with 

var totalWidth = this.value;
var doorSize = calcDoorSize(totalWidth);
doorWidthSlider.slider("option", "value", doorSize[0]);

But apparently the position of objects plays a role. Thank you!

Comment: @crabosse0 With the change made to `focusout`, I have re-arranged the existing code. Glad this solution helped you.

Answer (score 0):

You gotta write an onkeyupfunction to trigger the function while you writing new value into the input and the function is going to change the sliders.

```
$('.js-doorway-width').keyup(function(){
      $('#doorwayWidthSlider').slider('value',$('.js-doorway-width').val());
    });
```

This is the [**Demo**](http://cr8code.co/editor.php?workid=6b914dfb9cc130c51fa003bc1952b93f)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I can not enter a number in input. There are 650 value and I can not enter a number in input.

Comment: it is because your slider doesnt accept values lower than 650, and when you trying to erase your number become lesser than 650. Change the slider min value to 0 then try.